# Running a For Loop through a Multiline Powershell Variable

Tags: powershell

I have section of a script where the user enters a list of server names which then checks to make sure there they exist in AD and then runs a command on each of the ones that do exist.  This is what I have:

```
$machineNames = (read-host "Enter Server Name(s) (space separated)").Trim()

foreach ($machineName in (($machineNames).Split(' '))) {
    Try {
        Get-ADComputer $machineName | Out-Null
        $veriMachineNames += "$machineName`n"
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host "*****Invalid Machine Name:  $machineName" -Foreground Yellow
        Write-Host "*****Skipping $machineName`n" -Foreground Yellow
    }
}

foreach ($machine in $sepMachineNames) {
    Write-Host "Server: $machine `n"
}
```

When I run this part of the script I get the following output (error intentionally included):

```
PS C:\> C:\script.ps1

Enter Machine Name(s) (space separated): server1 server2 server3
*****Invalid Machine Name:  server3
*****Skipping server3

Server: server1
server2
```

As you can see it appears that the second foreach is seeing server1 and server2 as being on one line and not two lines.  Is there a way to do this with just a variable?  I'd rather not output the list to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating each name onto a big multi-line string manually, just output the individual names 1 by 1 and store them in a variable:

```
$veriMachines = foreach ($machineName in (($machineNames).Split(' '))) {
    Try {
        Get-ADComputer $machineName | Out-Null
        # no piping to `|Out-Null`, this will "bubble up" to the variable
        $machineName
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host "*****Invalid Machine Name:  $machineName" -Foreground Yellow
        Write-Host "*****Skipping $machineName`n" -Foreground Yellow
    }
}
```

Now `$veriMachines` is an array of string (the machine names we just verified) that you can iterate over:

```
foreach($machine in $veriMachines){
    Write-Host "Server: $machine"
}
```